# Regular Expression to match any string between the delimiters

Tags: regex, notepad++

Trying to match a strings in notepad++ with a regular expression.

The string I'm trying to match is formatted like this:

```
^*^1st Choice Housing. Inc~*~
```

The carets and tildes serve as the delimiters around the name.

Here's the regular expression I'm trying to use to match any string between the delimiters

```
\^\*\^([A-Za-z0-9-.]+)\~\*\~
```

Notepad++ says 0 matches. What is wrong with my regular expression?

If I use:

```
\^\*\^1st Choice Housing. Inc\~\*\~
```

It matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\^\*\^([ A-Za-z0-9.-]+)\~\*\~
```

You were missing a space, I added it at the beginning. And I rearranged your regex a bit and put `-` at the end, so there won't be any confusion about it possibly meaning a separation of a range of characters, such as `A-Z`.

Comment: This answer found the accurate number of results. I think the space at the beginning found more than the space at the end for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
\^\*\^([A-Za-z0-9-. ]+)\~\*\~
```

This includes the space you were lacking.